# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 41981 during tomcat start

Tags: java, tomcat

I am getting this exception during tomcat start. I am using **jdk1.8.0_152**, **apache-tomcat-8.5.24**

I have been updating my elasticsearch from version 1.7 to 6.0. For that I had to include few new jars and had to update few existing to latest versions.(commons-io-2.6,lucene-core-7.0.1,log4j-api-2.9.1) After that I am getting this error on tomcat starting.

> SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log
>   StandardWrapper.Throwable  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   41981     at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What version of asm do you use? According to this post https://github.com/joaoarthurbm/designwizard/issues/36:

> asm-3.1 doesn't support lambdas expression available in JDK 8.

So you might be want to upgrade to asm 5.0.1 or higher.

Comment: I added asm-6.0. Now I am getting java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) this error

Comment: Could you update your question with the exception? @Jerry

Comment: Please make sure only one version of asm exists in your classpath @Jerry

Comment: Even after removing asm old jar same exception is coming, is there a way I can find out which jar is causing this issue?